# Do up and down arrow keys navigate Gmail messages?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

It was the case until recently that I could scroll up and down either within a Gmail message or on the page containing the message by clicking there (just to make sure the cursor/focal point is there) and then pressing Up Arrow and Down Arrow. I am no longer able to do this. Has this feature been intentionally removed, and if so, why? Is this an anomalous bug? Have others experienced this behavior?

Page Up and Page Down still work. I am using Google Chrome.

**Update: Magically the feature is back on in Gmail! But still off in Google Apps mail.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have a bug right now. Check out [this forum thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=63b73e16fc20be32&hl=en) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell your browser to focus on the area that you want to navigate, usually by clicking or pressing the tab key.  Check out google experients to see if there might be some other keyboard shortcuts that won't interfere with message scrolling.

Comment: Please note from the question that I am unable to scroll after clicking to focus the cursor on the desired [part of the] page.

Comment: What operating system are you running?  What version of google chrome are you running?  You might consider clearing your cache and cookies, relogging into gmail.

Comment: I am running Chrome version 13.0 on Windows 7. The behavior has persisted through several restarts of the browser and a cache clearing in both Google Apps mail and Gmail.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not really sure what to think.